# Will Romeo meet Juliet?

Tags: mathematics, probability

Romeo and Juliet try to meet each other everyday at a certain place between 12:00 and 13:00. They arrive at the place at a random time between 12:00 and 13:00 and they wait 15 minutes (but never after 13:00). If nobody shows up they come back home. Every day, what is the probability that they meet each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ and $J$ be uniform $[0,1]$ random variables to represent the arrival times of Romeo and Juliet, respectively.  The star-crossed lovers meet if $|R-J|\le 1/4$.

The desired probability is the area of the shaded region [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b7gtv84asm), and this area is

> $(1-0)^2 - (3/4)^2 = 7/16$.